# Access OR statements does not work correctly

Tags: ms-access, criteria

Currently I am creating reports that are based off of three criteria, one specific criteria used for all seems to not work for my one report;

```
<> "09" OR <> "40" OR <> "42" OR <> "45" OR <> "46" OR <> "49" OR <> "52" OR <> "55" OR <> "75" OR <> "94"
```

--Used in Type field to not pull any of the numbers above

I have been using this for all of my other reports with no issues but it seems that for one of my reports it completely ignores the account type criteria (I have only two records pulled and one is a 75 which I shouldn't be pulling). In short, this database that is using data from all of the same table only doesn't work for one query. If I was to make the criteria only one number it'll work ( ex. <> "75" alone will remove the one record that I don't need) but I want to avoid having to make a query for each individual subtype. I have no idea why it'll works for all except one query/report. Any assistance would be appreciated or if someone has had this issue before. Access seems to have a mind of its own....

Answer (score 0):

A condition like:

```
Type <> "55" OR Type <> "75"
```

would return all the rows of the table, because in every row `Type <> "55"` or `Type <> "75"`, so I don't understand how is it possible that you *use this this for all of your other reports with no issues*.
If you want to exclude rows that have specific values in a column you should use the operator `AND`:

```
Type <> "55" AND Type <> "75" AND ......
```

or `NOT IN`:

```
Type NOT IN ("55", "75", ...)
```